# Finding the min/max value in a Mat while ignoring -100

Tags: c++, opencv, max, min, mat

I am trying to use opencv min() max() or MinMaxLoc() to get min and max values within a Mat. The way my mat is structured, data points with null or no data have a value of -100. Will these opencv functions ignore the -100 values or is there a way to get the minimum value while ignoring -100 values using predefined functions?

The alternative would be to iterate over the entire Mat manually and calculate min and max values while ignoring -100 but I would like to use built in functions if possible. Why reinvent the wheel.

Comment: A brief reduex of the OpenCV documentation shows no immediate mechanism for what you effectively want, which is "Give me the minimum/maximum, ignoring value X". Using a sentinel value is going to bone you one way or another. You could use `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()` to avoid min-colisions and/or overlaps with "real" min-values, but that would hose your "real" max calculation, and vice-versa. If there is a way to do this, I've not seen it yet, and would be curious if such a thing has been strung together.

Comment: Create a mask: cv::Mat mask = yourMat != -100; Then use minMaxLoc with mask parameter

Comment: @Micka What would happen if you specified a mask that is completely zero to `minMaxLoc`?  Is it undefined behaviour?  If so, would it be good practice to check if the mask is all zero before supplying to the method?... or if not, what is returned if we do supply a fully zero mask?

Comment: @rayryeng no idea, test it or have a look at the code, it is probably not that complex. But I could imagine that for min and max the first elements are returned, so if minVal==maxVal the whole matrix is filled with that value

Comment: @Micka doh. Why didn't I think of that? Lol. I figured it out. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/45dd575ed2c8458181cd0dd286fa22d1061a4065/modules/core/src/minmax.cpp. The min and max values are set to +/- infinity as defined in numeric limits initially, so if the mask is empty this is what is returned. Eck... Not what I was hoping for but it answers my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NAN`, which will be ignored by `minMaxLoc`:

```
Mat C = (Mat_<double>(3,3) << 0, -1, NAN, -1, 5, -1, 0, -1, 0);
cout << "C = " << endl << " " << C << endl << endl;
SparseMat S = SparseMat(C);

double minVal, maxVal;
minMaxLoc( S, &minVal, &maxVal );
cout << "minVal = " << minVal << endl;
cout << "maxVal = " << maxVal << endl;
```

Output:

```
C = 
 [0, -1, nan;
  -1, 5, -1;
  0, -1, 0]

minVal = -1
maxVal = 5
```

Incidentally, `min` and `max` compare **two elements** (or pairs of elements of identically-sized arrays) and gives you the minimum or maximum rather than finding the global min and max of an array, so these are probably not what you want.

Comment: So, how does any of this help the OP ignore values of -100?

Comment: @hvd That depends on whether the OP is willing/able to replace the -100 values with NAN.

Comment: I am able to change the array values to NaN when I create my MAT object at no performance decrease and then use the minMAxLoc()

Comment: This does not always work. In a `CV_32FC1` `Mat` containing NaN values, `minMaxLoc` gives me a max value of -3.40282e+38, which is utterly wrong. You're better off using a mask.

Comment: @R2-D2 Interesting. Can you give a sample matrix where this happened? I'm available in chat, if you want to do it that way. You did change `minVal` and `maxVal` to `float`, didn't you?

Comment: @beaker I did not change the type of `minVal` and `maxVal` to `float`, because it wouldn't compile (`minMaxLoc` expects `double*`). But I was able to find out, that the error only occours, when you initialize `Mat` with `NAN` and set some of its values later on, *not* vice versa.

Comment: @R2-D2 Yes, you're right about `minVal` and `maxVal`, of course. I have no idea why it would do that; the value you got for max looks nothing like a NaN, so it's not misinterpreting it. Very curious. If I get time later today I'll poke around in the source code.